# How to ensure that two variables are not =/= 0 at the same time with using binaries by classic approach?

Tags: variables, binary, modeling

In a model, I have two variables, b1 and b2, that both are free in sign. How can I force the model so that in the final solution their values are not set to zero at the same time?

I want to force the model so that in the final solution their values are not set to zero at the same time.